# get individual child value from parent tag using onclick method

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to get individual table id value with the individual button click. and I got the table id value but it shows all table id value's like (1234... 10).
How to get the individual table value (like clicking the 3rd button -> get 3rd table id only).
I am using both PHP and HTML code together.

This is my code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>S.No</b></td>
        <td><b>User Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Post Title</b></td>
        <td><b>Post Date</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            require_once('databaseconnection.php');
            $query  = "SELECT * FROM `userpost`";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%;" id="td_id" value="<?php echo " {$row[ 'postid']} "; ?>">
                <?php echo "{$row['postid']}"; ?>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%;" id="td_user">
                <?php echo "{$row['postuser']}"; ?>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 65%;" id="td_title">
                <?php echo "{$row['posttitle']}"; ?>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">
                <?php echo "{$row['postdate']}"; ?>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%;"><input id="getpostid" type="submit" value="view" onclick="actiongetpostid();"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
            ?>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function actiongetpostid() {
        var tdid = $('tr').children('#td_id').text();
        alert(tdid);

    }
</script>
```

HTML code:
This table will create dynamically.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 5%;" id="td_id" value="1">1</td>
    <td style="width: 15%;" id="td_user">rose</td>
    <td style="width: 65%;" id="td_title">YII2 framwork for PHP</td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">2016-02-12</td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><input id="getpostid" type="submit" value="view" onclick="actiongetpostid();"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 5%;" id="td_id" value="2">2</td>
    <td style="width: 15%;" id="td_user">rose</td>
    <td style="width: 65%;" id="td_title">Angular JS</td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">2016-02-12</td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><input id="getpostid" type="submit" value="view" onclick="actiongetpostid();"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 5%;" id="td_id" value="3">3</td>
    <td style="width: 15%;" id="td_user">murali</td>
    <td style="width: 65%;" id="td_title">EXT JS</td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">2016-02-12</td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><input id="getpostid" type="submit" value="view" onclick="actiongetpostid();"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am using this code within "while" loop so how to solve this issue. Please help me.

Comment: is it for deleting or updating data?

Comment: This is to display the datas from the mysql table.

Comment: i meant,  `id` is for deleting or updating from the list of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not sure why you are using `<input>` tags if you are just wanting to display the data. Use `<button>` tags instead.

On this note I would change your button `td` to something like:

```
<td style="width: 5%;"><button class="getpostid">View</button>
```

Note the use of `class="getpostid"`. The use of `id` would only apply to the first element with `getpostid` as IDs can only be used once.

Then using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.getpostid').click(function(){
        var tdid = $(this).parents('tr').find('#td_id').text();
        alert(tdid);
    });
});
```

Note the use of `parents()` instead of `parent()`. The latter can only go up one level in the DOM tree. Whereas the step needed is 2 levels.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96hbqobz/2/) with a working example.